# Why is it laggy when I scroll this list

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to show a list of installed apps and a checkbox next to each app. The scrolling is terrible, it's noticably laggy. It looks like i am doing something wrong but i can't figure it out. how can I improve it?

```
@Composable
fun AppList(infoList: MutableList<android.content.pm.ResolveInfo>) {
    val ctx = LocalContext.current

    LazyColumn {
        items(infoList) { info ->
            var isChecked by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
            var icon by remember { mutableStateOf(info.loadIcon(ctx.packageManager)) }
            var label by remember { mutableStateOf( info.loadLabel(ctx.packageManager).toString()) }
            Row(
                verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically, modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
            ) {
              
                Image(
                    painter = rememberImagePainterMine(icon),
                    contentDescription = label,
                    contentScale = ContentScale.Fit,
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp)
                )


                // Display the app name
                Text(
                    text =label,
                    style = MaterialTheme.typography.bodyMedium,
                    modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)
                )

                // Display the checkbox on the right
                Box(modifier = Modifier.clickable { isChecked = !isChecked }) {
                    Checkbox(
                        checked = isChecked,
                        onCheckedChange = { isChecked = it },
                        modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp)
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun rememberImagePainterMine(drawable: Drawable): Painter = remember(drawable) {
    object : Painter() {
        override val intrinsicSize: Size
            get() = Size(drawable.intrinsicWidth.toFloat(), drawable.intrinsicHeight.toFloat())

        override fun DrawScope.onDraw() {
            drawable.setBounds(0, 0, size.width.toInt(), size.height.toInt())
            drawable.draw(this.drawContext.canvas.nativeCanvas)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you running your app in release mode? It makes a big difference as to how smooth Jetpack Compose will be (due to the amount of debug code under the hood).

[Google themselves explain it as follows](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/performance):

> If you're finding performance issues, make sure to try running your app in release mode. Debug mode is useful for spotting lots of problems, but it imposes a significant performance cost, and can make it hard to spot other code issues that might be hurting performance. You should also use the R8 compiler to remove unnecessary code from your app. By default, building in release mode automatically uses the R8 compiler.

Additionally, you should consider [using keys with your `LazyColumn`](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/performance/bestpractices#use-lazylist-keys) to help Compose figure out if your data moves around or changes completely.

> Without your help, Compose doesn't realize that unchanged items are just being moved in the list. Instead, Compose thinks the old "item 2" was deleted and a new one was created, and so on for item 3, item 4, and all the way down. The result is that Compose recomposes every item on the list, even though only one of them actually changed.

> The solution here is to provide item keys. Providing a stable key for each item lets Compose avoid unnecessary recompositions. In this case, Compose can see that the item now at spot 3 is the same item that used to be at spot 2. Since none of the data for that item has changed, Compose doesn't have to recompose it.